# Pickling a Function and Include the Imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

My idea is this, so I want to allow users to send code to a web endpoint.

I would like to grab the modules/imports from the method.
Is that possible?

```
import pickle
import inspect

def add(x,y):
    return x+y

def stringify_method(func):
    """"""
    return pickle.dumps(func)

print(pickle.loads(stringify_method(add))(1,2))
3
```

So it returns 3, which is expected.

Now let's say I have something more complicated:

```
import sys
import pickle
import inspect
import arcpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def create_array(array):
    return np.array(array)

def unpickle_method(func):
    """"""
    return pickle.dumps(func)

print(pickle.loads(stringify_method(create_array))([1,2,3,4]))
```

I get the method just fine, but the modules do not follow.  How do I get my `import numpy as np` and pandas, etc..?

Comment: How can you find yourself in this situation? What is the bigger picture here?

Comment: Sending code to a remote server to distribute my workload across many machine

Comment: What's the actual problem you're having? Pickle should be able to import whatever it needs to unpickle your objects (or raise an exception if it can'). Of course it won't put those modules into the global namespace of whatever module happened to call `loads`, but I can't see why you'd expect it to, or what the benefit of it doing so would be. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: That does not depend on `pickle` at all. Why are you not using something like hadoop or spark?

Comment: good idea on hadoop, but it's not the answer for this question.

Comment: If you're trying to avoid needing to have numpy installed on the remote machine, that's not possible. If you have values or functions that fail to unpickle on the remote machine, you may be able to just use `cloudpickle` (if you expect your two setups to be identical) or `dill` (if you don't) instead of plain `pickle`. You also might want to consider using a distributed computing library that wraps up the pickling, dispatching, etc. rather than trying to build one from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but is this helpful?

```
>>> import sys
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import inspect
>>> 
>>> [x[0] for x in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.ismodule)]
['__builtins__', 'inspect', 'np', 'sys']
```

> this gets me 1/2 way there, I need to be able to then grab the import statements from the method: import numpy as np

You could probably reconstruct the statements from this:

```
>>> [(x, y.__name__) for x,y in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.ismodule)]
[('__builtins__', 'builtins'), ('inspect', 'inspect'), ('np', 'numpy'), ('sys', 'sys')]
```

(note the `('np', 'numpy')` element which tells you `import numpy as np`)

Comment: this gets me 1/2 way there, I need to be able to then grab the import statements from the method: import numpy as np

Comment: I think that'll do!

Comment: This is both amazing and horrible. There's surely a flaw in the premise of the question.

Comment: @roganjosh I agree. I hacked this together without being aware of all the possible pitfalls. So use with care, OP.

Comment: You're getting an upvote anyway because it's shown me some things I should learn :)